# No matching function found when using nontype template parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, non-type-template-parameter

I am learning templates in C++ using the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). So trying out(writing) different examples to clear my concepts. In particular, i learned that we can use templates to pass array by reference as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
template<unsigned int N>
void printSize(double (&arr)[N])
{
    std::cout<<"size is: "<<N<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    double arr1[] = {1,2,3};
    printSize(arr1); //this works as expected 
}
```

The above is just a contrived example which i understand. While the example given below, i am unable to understand.

```
#include <iostream>
template<unsigned int N>
void printSizeTwo(double (&arr)[N+1]) //is this valid? I mean what will N+1 mean here if it is indeed valid.
{
    std::cout<<"size is: "<<N<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    double arr1[] = {1,2,3};
    printSizeTwo(arr1); //why doesn't this call work?
    
}
```

My question is that in my second code snippet, is writing `N+1` valid? If yes, then what does it mean that is., how is it different from the first code snippet where we have only `N` instead of `N+1`. Basically, i want to understand why the call to `printSizeTwo(arr1)` doesn't work and how can i make it work.

Comment: `N+1` is valid, but it's a non-deduced context - the compiler cannot infer `N` automatically from the call. You can provide `N` explicitly: `printSizeTwo<2>(arr1);` (though of course this rather defeats the purpose of this particular function). The standard doesn't require compilers to solve arithmetic problems, like "what should `N` be to make `N+1 == 3`".

Comment: Ok then i guess i should delete this question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So is there any reason for allowing this. I mean is it useful anywhere?

Comment: Please don't delete the question. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @cigien Ok not deleting.

Comment: A reason for allowing arithmetic on template parameters? Well, consider something like `template <int N, int M> void concatenate(double (&first)[N], double (&second)[M], double (&out)[N + M]);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If there isn't a reasonable duplicate target, perhaps you could post your comments as an answer?